# combine multiple DataViews into a single one?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 4 different select statements which i sequently assign to an sqlDataSource like this:

```
sqlNoutatiProduse.SelectCommand = select;
```

and i keep the results in different DataViews like

```
MySession.Current.dataViewNoutatiProduse1 = (System.Data.DataView)sqlNoutatiProduse.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
```

and so on.

Is it possible to combine into a single DataView the results of these queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more details, this is the best generic answer I can give...

It's possible to create a DataTable manually, add the columns you need, and then loop through the DataViews to add records to your new table.  I've used this technique where I can't do the work at the DB level.  However, this would be horribly inefficient.

You'd be better off seeing if you can get the data you want it directly from the DB.